# I am looking for a hadith regarding periods and pregnancy pain

Tags: hadith, source-identification

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarities_between_the_Bible_and_the_Qur%27an#Adam_and_Eve_.28.D8.A2.D8.AF.D9.85_Adam_and_.D8.AD.D9.88.D8.A7.D8.A1_Hawwaa.29), there is a quote without a citation:

> But in the Hadith, it is mentioned that women will suffer from periods
>   and will bear pregnancy pain.

is there such a Hadith?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, that is a misquote as there is no such Hadith. It should have been :
*"But in the **Bible**, it is mentioned that women will suffer from periods and will bear pregnancy pain."*

Because, Bible clearly states, in [Gen 3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0103.htm):

> 16. Unto the woman He said: 'I will greatly multiply thy pain and thy travail; in pain thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.'

There is no concept of **[original sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_sin)**, i.e. inherited sin, in Islam<sup>[ref](http://www.religionfacts.com/islam/beliefs/human.htm)</sup>, because the [sin of Adam was forgiven](http://quran.com/2/37), and [Eve was never cursed like that](http://www.islamawareness.net/Adam/original.html).

<sup><sup>bdw, I have [edited](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Biblical_and_Quranic_narratives&oldid=601700856) the wiki page</sup></sup>